# Advanced Webapp2 Routing

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

In old school webapp, app.yaml based routing allowed you to check for regular expressions and if matched, process a request by a handler whose name is based on the found pattern. For example \1_handler.py would dispatch to user_handler.py if the matched pattern was 'user'.

Is there a way to do the same thing with webapp2.Route? Can the lazy handler or the method_handler parameters be based on the matched patterns in template?

Comment: You're talking about two different things here - app.yaml and your web framework. You can still use app.yaml-based routing with webapp2.

Comment: Yes I know. But what I want to do is to get the request handled by a different method in a request handler class based on the content of the URL. So if it's user/show I want it to go Handler:show and if it's user/add I want it to go to User:add. And I'm doing that for three types of entities (user+2) and 5 types of actions. You can do it in 15 routes ineebapp2. But I'm seeing how I can narrow it down to 3 or 1. I don't see how app.yaml definition will allow me to define the metho.

Comment: It won't, but that's not what you were asking in the original question. I'm not sure how it relates, actually.

Comment: "Can the lazy handler or the method_handler parameters be based on the matched patterns in template?"

Comment: You seemed to be talking about routing to modules based on the path, not choosing methods. Regardless, what you're trying to do is not really in line with the RESTful spirit of webapp2, which has each distinct function handled by a distinct handler class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

webapp2 does not allow to route like that. I think the most reasonable solution is to write a custom dispatcher for `webapp2.Router`.

It is possible to set a custom dispatcher like this:

```
app = WSGIApplication(...)
app.router.set_dispatcher(custom_dispatcher)
```

Here is a **not tested sketch** for dispatcher, code is based on `webapp2.Router.default_dispatcher`:

```
from webapp2 import import_string

def custom_dispatcher(router, request, response):
    route, args, kwargs = rv = router.match(request)
    request.route, request.route_args, request.route_kwargs = rv

    handler = route.handler
    if isinstance(handler, basestring):

        handler, args, kwargs = _parse_handler_template(handler, args, kwargs)

        if handler not in self.handlers:
            router.handlers[handler] = handler = import_string(handler)
        else:
            handler = router.handlers[handler]

    return router.adapt(handler)(request, response)

def _parse_handler_template(handler, args, kwargs):
    """replace {key} in `handler` with values from `args` or `kwargs`.
    Replaced values are removed from args/kwargs."""
    args = list(args)
    kwargs = dict(kwargs)
    def sub(match):
        if kwargs:
            return kwargs.pop(match.group().strip('{}'))
        else:
            return args.pop(int(match.group().strip('{}'))
    return re.sub('{.*?}', sub, handler), args, kwargs
```

This code should allow to register a rules like this:

```
 app = WSGIApplication([
     (r'module/<module>/<action>/<argument>', 'modules.{module}.action_{action}'),
 ])
```

This example does not allow to use variables from pattern in method name, for example: `module.Class:action_{method}`. In `Route` class this endpoint is split by semicolon and values stored in `route.method_name` and `route.handler`.